# Primary key error when adding record to database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, odbc

I have pretty much followed the article on MSDN, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx to add a new row to a table.  This is my implementation, I have only included the relevant part:

```
        this.booksTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;

        DataRow row = core.Tables["books"].NewRow();

        row[0] = 1234567;               //primary key
        row[3] = book_name;             //string

        //add
        core.Tables["books"].Rows.Add(row);
        //update
        booksTableAdapter.Update(core); //generates error
```

When executed, I get '[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]:
Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value' 
despite explicitly setting the primary key.  The error is the same if I do not set a primary key.  I always assumed Access would automatically generate a primary key regardless of my code.  How can I fix this error?  Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Check your database table with MS Access and confirm that your primary key is composed only from the field at position 0

Comment: your pk could be a composite one, formed by multiple columns

Comment: The primary key is long integer, generated at random.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your swift reponse.  There was more than one primary key (created by mistake). I removed the unecessary second pk and it works fine.